# React history.push allow user to open in new tab

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Navigation between pages in my navbar is done using an onClick handler, rather than through hrefs. When doing this, I can't either middle click to open in a new tab or right click on the link and select open in new tab. I am using react-router-v4.

An example of a route.

```
<a onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/conference/')}>Conference</a>
```

Is there a way to allow this to happen in react or should I be using hrefs instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `<Link to='/conference'>Conference</Link>` to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Link` from react router

```js
<Link to={`/conference`}>Conference</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not using the [`Link`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) component?

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you do want to programmatically link to other pages and NOT use  you can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62703848/1205281) to enable cmd/ctrl clicking.

Tl;dr when ctrl/cmd is pressed put a flag on the state, then use it to select whether to `history.push` or `window.open` the new path.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
window.open('/conference', '_blank')
```

Comment: Thank you and welcome @german-st, Can you provide an explanation for the answer, as it is very short