# open window using react-router v4's this.props.history.push?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I know we can use a Link tag and pass in target="_blank" like

```
<Link to="/" target="_blank">Hello World</Link>
```

but I am having trouble finding out I can do that with this.props.history.push... I am using that to pass in a pathname and search string...

```
    let searchString = queryString.stringify({
      rangeEnd: data.programEnd,
    });

    this.props.history({
      pathname: `/machines/${machineId}`,
      search: searchString,
      target: "_blank // need something like this, not seeing it in docs
    });
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. See similar question here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37999941/2852119

Comment: I was overthinking this. Rishabhs answer probably works for 85% of cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

History push changes address in the same window.

One option could be using window.open()

```
const url = `#/machines/${machineId}?${searchString}`;
window.open(url);
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer